# remover coluna certa

Tags: angularjs, html5, tabela-html

Com base em um script da resposta a essa pergunta: [Tabela dinamica com angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220622/tabela-dinamica-com-angular/246473#246473)

Onde o mesmo cria uma tabela dinâmica com angular, porém ele não consegue excluir a "célula" certa, ele sempre exclui a última questão incluída. Para reproduzir o erro é só marcar o primeiro `radio button` da primeira coluna e tentar excluir a pergunta, ele permanecerá e excluirá o da coluna da direita.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, total) {
    total = parseInt(total);
    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
      input.push(i);
    }
    return input;
  };
});

app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  // criando variavel de perguntas
  $scope.answer = ["Sim", "Não"];
  // criando variavel de questão
  $scope.question = [{
      'name': "P 1",
      'r': [false, false]
    },
    {
      'name': "P 2",
      'r': [false, false]
    }
  ];
  // adicionando pergunta 
  $scope.addAnswer = function() {
    $scope.answer.push("R" + (new Date().getTime()));
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.question.length; i++) {
      $scope.question[i].r.push('false');
    }
  };
  // excluindo pergunta
  $scope.delAnswer = function(index) {
    $scope.answer.splice(index, 1);
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.question.length; i++) {
      $scope.question[i].r.splice(index - 1, 1);
    }
  };
  // adicionando questão
  $scope.addQuestion = function() {
    $r = $scope.answer.map(function() {
      return false;
    });
    $scope.question.push({
      'name': 'P' + (new Date().getTime()),
      'r': $r
    });
  };
  // excluindo questão
  $scope.delQuestion = function(index){
      $scope.question.splice(index, 1);
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>
    <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>Perguntas:</td>
        <td ng-repeat="a in answer">
          <input value="{{a}}" style="width:40px" />
          <button ng-click="delAnswer($index)"> - </button>
        </td>
        <td><button type="button" ng-click="addAnswer()"> + </button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="q in question">
        <td><input value="{{q.name}}" /></td>
        <td ng-repeat="b in q.r track by $index">
          <input type="radio" name="{{q.name}}" />
        </td>
        <td><button ng-click="delQuestion($index)"> - </button>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button ng-click="addQuestion()"> + </button>
        </td>
        <tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

OBS.: Creio que o erro esta na função `delAnswer`, mas não estou conseguindo achar o erro.